# How can I update inventory on Overstock.com using API

Tags: php, api, curl

I try to update inventory on supplieroasis.com using API. But I does not get update on https://edge.supplieroasis.com while api return success respnose.

I also like to know how supplier oasis take inventory for "reserved", "sellable", "onHold", "totalQuantity".

```
$user_pass = "XXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXX";
$header = array('Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($user_pass),'Content-Type:application/xml');    
date_default_timezone_set("America/Denver");
$current_time  = mktime(date("H")-1, date("i"), date("s"), date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y"));
$inventory_at=  date("c",$current_time);    
$xml = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<supplierInventoryMessage xmlns="api.supplieroasis.com">
<supplierInventory>
    <partnerSku>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</partnerSku>
    <supplierWarehouseQuantity>
        <warehouseName>
            <code>XXXXXXXXXXX</code>
        </warehouseName>
        <quantity>13</quantity>
        <timestamp>$inventory_at</timestamp>            
    </supplierWarehouseQuantity>
</supplierInventory>    
</supplierInventoryMessage>
EOD;
$ch = curl_init();        
$url = 'https://api.supplieroasis.com/inventory?jobName=';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,150);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$str = curl_exec($ch);
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
header("Content-Type:text/XML");
print_r($str);
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: @ M A SIDDIQUI I updated with code, please give positive comments.

Comment: @kirit I am too struggling with Overstock supplier oasis API. I need just a initial startup help I can't get proper support from overstock supplier oasis. So Can you please guide me through? Here is my email mtarique@outlook.com

Answer (score 1):

I just successfully set up the Overstock API and passed the initial tests with the Oasis integrations team.

I recommend you first get the sample API calls working that they provide on their support site and then modify these to your needs.

Here is a link to a working API call example for the inventory API:

```
REQUEST:

GET https://api.test.supplieroasis.com/inventory

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
content-type: application/xml
Authorization: Basic
accept: application/xml
Host: api.test.supplieroasis.com
```

The Authorization is your Oasis username and PW with Base64 encryption. This is provided by the Oasis Integration staff assigned to your company.